# Promise regresa un objeto y se queda en Pending

Tags: ajax, promesas

Estoy haciendo resolviendo una petición a una llamada ajax, pero no entiendo porqué me está regresando el objeto promesa con pending, si la llamada Ajax me regresa de forma exitosa los datos.

Aquí mi código

```
        getQuote: function(uniqueid){
            let urlAjax = this.endpoint;
            return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
                $.ajax({
                    url: urlAjax,
                    data: {unique: uniqueid},
                    method: "GET"
                })
                .done(result => {
                    resolve(result);
                })
                .fail(reject)
            });
        },
```

La forma en la que quiero obtener la información de la promesa:

```
var testQuote = this.getQuote(this.uniqueid);
```

el resultado con console.log:

Un objeto promesa.

He intentado también con una función async y utilizando await, pero regresa lo mismo, también con Promise.resolve() y lo mismo

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias!

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Acabo de hacer una función async extra para poder esperar 2 veces la llamada, y descubrí esto:

En este console log si me imprime el arreglo de datos

```
fetchQuote: async function($uniqueid){
            const data = await this.getQuote($uniqueid);
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        },
```

y cuando hago esto:

```
var testQuote = this.fetchQuote(this.uniqueid);
 console.log(testQuote);
```

Me imprime la promesa en pending! como puede ser eso posible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Camarada, el problema esta en como obtienes el valor que regresa la promesa.
Recuerda que una promesa es una llamada asincrona así que cuando devuelve un valor no lo hace siguiendo la secuencia normal de ejecución.

Es decir, si tu haces esto:

```
var testQuote = this.fetchQuote(this.uniqueid);
console.log(testQuote);
```

Recibes un pending porque en el momento que se ejecuta este codigo: `console.log(testQuote);`
La promesa aun no se ha resuelto. Aunque a tus ojos parezca que si.

Puedes agregar un breakpoint dentro del resolve de la promesa y veras como primero va a ejecutar el console log, y después va a detenerse en el resolve... es decir, el console.log se ejecutara antes del resolve.

Por eso al usar promesas se usan el .then()  y el .catch.
Esos métodos solo se ejecutaran cuando la promesa haya terminado.
Si termina de manera satisfactoria, entonces se va a ejecutar el then() y si no, entonces será el catch().

Al final, para obtener el valor que regresa la promesa, tu código debería quedar así:

```
this.fetchQuote(this.uniqueid)
.then(
     (testQuote) => {
       console.log(testQuote);
     }
)
.catch(function(error) {
   console.log(error);
});
```

Te puse el then con una función flecha y el catch con función normal para que veas que se puede con cualquiera de las 2.

Sale, espero y te sirva.

Comment: Gracias, si lo que estaba sucediendo era que necesitaba asignar mi variable this.testQuote dentro de la resolución de la promesa en el then, si lo hacía afuera seguía en Pending porque no terminaba de resolver.